# List of figures with figure source

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, koma-script, source

So basically I need a list of figures where the source is also shown like this:
[image]
I am using Koma-Scripts report class and my figures look like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{Images/B_Bosonen}
        \caption{Tabelle der Elementarteilchen.}
        \label{fig:B:Bosonen}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the caption below the image and the one for the lof separately: `\caption[<caption for lof>]{<caption for below the image>}`.

Please note that `[H]` is basically a guarantee for bad placement of your images (I suggest `[htbp]`) and `\begin{center}...\end{center}` will add additional vertical space - better use `\centering` instead.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image}
        \caption[Tabelle der Elementarteilchen. \url{www.google.com} besucht am ...]{Tabelle der Elementarteilchen.}
        \label{fig:B:Bosonen}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is ist possile to change the 1 in the front to Fig. 1?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on the class/packages you use. Please ask a new question including a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).